# Trying to get the elements of a page when it fully loads but I either get undefined or null. Why?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I've been working on this for two days now and I still can't figure out why my elements are sometimes either returning null or other times returning undefined but never returning the properties themselves. I've set their ID's in the respective HTML file and I still get null or undefined.

I've tried using setTimeout() but that didn't work because I was redirecting to a new page. I tried using an event listener on the document with DOMContentLoaded. I've even tried window.onload

```
var userEmailDisplay;
var newPaswordInput;
var confNewPaswordInput;
var submitNewPasswordBtn;

const urlParams = getAllUrlParams(window.location.href);
const actionCode = urlParams.oobCode;

window.onload = () => {
  var doc = document;
  switch (urlParams.mode) {
    case 'resetPassword':
      handleResetPassword(actionCode);
      break;
    case 'recoverEmail':
      handleRecoverEmail(actionCode);
      break;
    case 'verifyEmail':
      handleVerifyEmail(actionCode);
      break;
  }

  // get new password elements
  /*   if (window.location.href.indexOf("new-password") > -1) {
      userEmailDisplay = doc.getElementById('account-email-new-pswd');
      newPaswordInput = doc.getElementById('new-password-input');
      confNewPaswordInput = doc.getElementById('conf-new-password-input');
      submitNewPasswordBtn = doc.getElementById('update-pswd-sub-btn');
    } */

}

function handleResetPassword(actionCode) {
  // Verify the password reset code is valid.
  auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function (email) {
    window.location.href = "https://couch-potato-880f0.firebaseapp.com/email/new-password.html";
    console.log("code verified");

    confirmThePswdReset(actionCode, email);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

function confirmThePswdReset(actionCode, email) {
  window.onload = () => {
    userEmailDisplay = document.getElementById('account-email-new-pswd');
    newPaswordInput = document.getElementById('new-password-input');
    confNewPaswordInput = document.getElementById('conf-new-password-input');
    submitNewPasswordBtn = document.getElementById('update-pswd-sub-btn');
    console.log(submitNewPasswordBtn + ' + ' + userEmailDisplay);
    if (submitNewPasswordBtn && userEmailDisplay) {
      submitNewPasswordBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const accountEmail = email;
        console.log('submit btn clicked');
        const newPassword = newPaswordInput.value;
        const confNewPasswordValue = confNewPaswordInput.value;
        userEmailDisplay.innerHTML = `Email: ${accountEmail}`;
        if (newPassword != confNewPasswordValue) {
          alert('The new passwords must match!');
          return;
        }
        console.log(newPassword);
        // Save the new password.
        auth.confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword).then(function (resp) {
          // Password reset has been confirmed and new password updated.
          alert("All good");
          window.location.replace('/email/confirm-password-reset.html');
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I expect when I click the submit button on the new password page, there's the alert box to pop up saying that everything is good and the password has been reset but that never happens. The code only goes up to the if-statement that checks if submitNewPasswordBtn and userEmailDisplay exist and are not null. I know that because I never get an output log saying that the submit button was clicked. Sometimes I never even get the output checking that submitNewPasswordBtn and userEmailDisplay exist and have values.

Comment: Because JavaScript is also an asynchronous language and that it is managed using the promises => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: I'm a little bit confused on how it helps. Can you explain further?

Comment: googlelize " tuto Javascript Promise "